Dataset of words and their morphological variants in easy to use format?
I tried for the past few hours to list all lexemes in WordNet (in Node.js), and for each lexeme list its morphological variants, but couldn't quite make it work, and started seeming to need to hardcode morphological transformation rules myself.
import { promises as fs } from 'fs'
import path from 'path'

interface WordForms {
  word: string
  pos: string
  forms: string[]
}

class WordNet {
  private files = {
    n: { index: 'index.noun', exc: 'noun.exc' },
    v: { index: 'index.verb', exc: 'verb.exc' },
  }

  private fileContents = {
    index: {} as Record<string, string>,
    exc: {} as Record<string, string>,
  }

  constructor(private wordnetPath: string) {}

  async loadFiles(): Promise<void> {
    for (const [pos, files] of Object.entries(this.files)) {
      // Load index files
      try {
        const content = await fs.readFile(
          path.join(this.wordnetPath, files.index),
          'utf8',
        )
        this.fileContents.index[pos] = content
      } catch (err) {
        console.error(`Error loading ${files.index}:`, err)
        this.fileContents.index[pos] = ''
      }

      // Load exception files
      try {
        const content = await fs.readFile(
          path.join(this.wordnetPath, files.exc),
          'utf8',
        )
        this.fileContents.exc[pos] = content
      } catch (err) {
        console.error(`Error loading ${files.exc}:`, err)
        this.fileContents.exc[pos] = ''
      }
    }
  }

  private findBaseFormInIndex(word: string, pos: string): Set<string> {
    const forms = new Set<string>()
    const lines = this.fileContents.index[pos].split('\n')

    for (const line of lines) {
      if (!line.trim() || line.startsWith('  ')) continue

      // Extract the word and pointer symbols
      const parts = line.split(' ').filter(p => p.length > 0)
      if (parts.length < 3) continue

      const headWord = parts[0]
      const hasRelatedForms =
        line.includes(' + ') || line.includes(' @ ')

      // Direct match
      if (headWord === word && hasRelatedForms) {
        forms.add(word)
        // Look for related base forms
        if (headWord.endsWith('ing') || headWord.endsWith('tion')) {
          const base = headWord.replace(/(ing|tion)$/, '')
          forms.add(base)
          forms.add(base + 'e') // For cases like compute->computing
        }
      }

      // Related form match
      if (hasRelatedForms) {
        const baseWord = headWord.replace(
          /(ing|tion|ize|ise|ed|s)$/,
          '',
        )
        if (baseWord === word || headWord.startsWith(word)) {
          forms.add(headWord)
          forms.add(baseWord)
          if (!baseWord.endsWith('e')) {
            forms.add(baseWord + 'e') // For cases like comput->compute
          }
        }
      }
    }

    return forms
  }

  async getWordForms(word: string): Promise<WordForms[]> {
    const results: WordForms[] = []
    const baseWord = word.toLowerCase()

    for (const [pos, _] of Object.entries(this.files)) {
      const forms = this.findBaseFormInIndex(baseWord, pos)

      // Check exceptions
      const excContent = this.fileContents.exc[pos]
      if (excContent) {
        excContent.split('\n').forEach(line => {
          if (!line.trim()) return
          const [variant, base] = line.trim().split(' ')
          if (
            base === baseWord ||
            variant === baseWord ||
            forms.has(base) ||
            forms.has(variant)
          ) {
            forms.add(base)
            forms.add(variant)
          }
        })
      }

      if (forms.size > 0) {
        // Clean up forms
        const cleanedForms = Array.from(forms)
          .filter(f => f && f.length > 1)
          .sort()

        if (cleanedForms.length > 1) {
          results.push({
            word: baseWord,
            pos: pos === 'n' ? 'noun' : 'verb',
            forms: cleanedForms,
          })
        }
      }
    }

    return results
  }
}

interface Lemma {
  word: string
  pos: string
}

async function getAllLemmas(): Promise<Lemma[]> {
  // WordNet data is typically installed in these locations
  const possiblePaths = [
    '/opt/homebrew/Cellar/wordnet/3.1_1/dict',
    // Add the path from your natural library installation if different
  ]

  const posFiles = {
    n: 'index.noun',
    v: 'index.verb',
    a: 'index.adj',
    r: 'index.adv',
  }

  const lemmas: Lemma[] = []

  // Find the first valid WordNet path
  let wordnetPath = ''
  for (const p of possiblePaths) {
    try {
      await fs.access(p)
      wordnetPath = p
      break
    } catch {
      continue
    }
  }

  if (!wordnetPath) {
    throw new Error(
      'WordNet dictionary not found. Please ensure WordNet is installed.',
    )
  }

  // Read each index file
  for (const [pos, filename] of Object.entries(posFiles)) {
    try {
      const filePath = path.join(wordnetPath, filename)
      const content = await fs.readFile(filePath, 'utf8')

      // Parse file line by line
      const lines = content.split('\n')
      for (const line of lines) {
        // Skip comment lines and empty lines
        if (line && !line.startsWith(' ') && !line.startsWith('  ')) {
          const word = line.split(' ')[0] // First word on each line is the lemma
          if (word && !word.includes('_')) {
            // Skip multi-word expressions
            lemmas.push({ word, pos })
          }
        }
      }
    } catch (err) {
      console.error(`Error reading ${filename}:`, err)
    }
  }

  return lemmas
}

// Example usage
async function example() {
  try {
    const lemmas = (await getAllLemmas()).slice(11000, 11200)
    console.log(`Total lemmas found: ${lemmas.length}`)

    const wordnetPath = '/opt/homebrew/Cellar/wordnet/3.1_1/dict'
    const wordnet = new WordNet(wordnetPath)

    console.log('Loading WordNet files...')
    await wordnet.loadFiles()
    console.log('Files loaded')

    // Print first 10 lemmas
    for (const lemma of lemmas) {
      if (lemma.word.match(/\d+/)) continue
      console.log(`\nRelated forms for "${lemma.word}":`)
      const forms = await wordnet.getWordForms(lemma.word)

      forms.forEach(result => {
        console.log(`\nPart of speech: ${result.pos}`)
        console.log('Related forms:', result.forms.join(', '))
      })
    }

    // Count by part of speech
    const posCounts = lemmas.reduce((acc, lemma) => {
      acc[lemma.pos] = (acc[lemma.pos] || 0) + 1
      return acc
    }, {} as Record<string, number>)

    console.log('\nCounts by part of speech:')
    console.log(posCounts)
  } catch (err) {
    console.error('Error:', err)
  }
}

example()

export { getAllLemmas, Lemma }

interface LemmaVariants {
  lemma: string
  pos: string
  forms: string[]
  synsetOffsets: number[] // We need these to look up variants
}

async function getLemmaVariants(
  wordnetPath: string,
  word: string,
): Promise<LemmaVariants[]> {
  const posFiles = {
    n: { index: 'index.noun', data: 'data.noun' },
    v: { index: 'index.verb', data: 'data.verb' },
    a: { index: 'index.adj', data: 'data.adj' },
    r: { index: 'index.adv', data: 'data.adv' },
  }

  const results: LemmaVariants[] = []

  // Check each POS file
  for (const [pos, files] of Object.entries(posFiles)) {
    try {
      // First read the index file to get synset offsets
      const indexContent = await fs.readFile(
        path.join(wordnetPath, files.index),
        'utf8',
      )

      // Find the line for our word
      const indexLine = indexContent
        .split('\n')
        .find(line => line.startsWith(word + ' '))

      if (indexLine) {
        // Parse synset offsets from index line
        const parts = indexLine.split(' ').filter(p => p.length > 0)
        const synsetCount = parseInt(parts[2], 10)
        const synsetOffsets = parts
          .slice(-synsetCount)
          .map(o => parseInt(o, 8))

        // Now read the data file to get variants
        const dataContent = await fs.readFile(
          path.join(wordnetPath, files.data),
          'utf8',
        )

        const forms = new Set<string>()
        forms.add(word)

        // Look up each synset
        for (const offset of synsetOffsets) {
          // Find the data line at the offset
          const dataLines = dataContent.split('\n')
          const dataLine = dataLines.find(line =>
            line.startsWith(offset.toString(8).padStart(8, '0')),
          )

          if (dataLine) {
            // Extract variants from the data line
            const matches = dataLine.matchAll(/\{([^}]+)\}/g)
            for (const match of matches) {
              const variants = match[1].split(',').map(v => v.trim())
              variants.forEach(v => forms.add(v))
            }
          }
        }

        results.push({
          lemma: word,
          pos,
          forms: Array.from(forms),
          synsetOffsets,
        })
      }
    } catch (err) {
      console.error(`Error reading ${pos} files:`, err)
    }
  }

  return results
}

Is this data just not in WordNet? Is there a way to get the list of plurals -s, -ed, -ing, -tion, -tions, etc., for each word? If not from WordNet, then some other dataset?
